# Data not found in nested list after initialization

Tags: python

I have data that can be described as a series of objects in rows and columns. I am trying to store the objects in a nested list.  However, when I try to access the object within the nested list I don't get any value.

To better understand if data is being added, I am able to confirm the data is present when I query the object within the initialization loops, so I think I have a scope issue, but I'm not quite sure why the scope is working this way.

Here's the code

```
class Point :
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def set_x(self, x):
    self.x = x
  def set_y(self, y):
    self.y = y
  def get_x(self):
    return self.x
  def get_y(self):
    return self.y

def print_list (row) :
  for point in row :
    print(f"{point.get_x():.0f}, {point.get_y():.0f} | ", end='')
  print(' ;')

def print_nested_list (nested_list):
  for row in column_list :
    for point in row : 
      print(f"{point.get_x():.0f}, {point.get_y():.0f} | ", end='')
    print(' ;')
      
col = 0
MAX_COL = 5
row = 0
MAX_ROW = 5

column_list = []
row_list = []

while (col < MAX_COL) : 
  col += 1
  while (row < MAX_ROW) :
    row += 1
    point = Point()
    point.set_x(row)
    point.set_y(col)
    row_list.append(point)
  print_list(row_list)
  column_list.append(row_list)
  row = 0
  row_list.clear()

print_nested_list(column_list)
```

Here's the result:

```
# result of print from inside the while loops
1, 1 | 2, 1 | 3, 1 | 4, 1 | 5, 1 |  ;
1, 2 | 2, 2 | 3, 2 | 4, 2 | 5, 2 |  ;
1, 3 | 2, 3 | 3, 3 | 4, 3 | 5, 3 |  ;
1, 4 | 2, 4 | 3, 4 | 4, 4 | 5, 4 |  ;
1, 5 | 2, 5 | 3, 5 | 4, 5 | 5, 5 |  ;

# result of print outside the while loops 
 ;
 ;
 ;
 ;
 ;
```

Comment: You are clearing `row_list` after adding a reference to it to `column_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the row_list.clear() at end. This is wiping the data in row_list which is being referenced by column_list.

One way to get around this is by copying the object so when you append the row_list into column_list instead pass row_list.copy().

I would also note that in print_nested_list(...) you're not using the parameter supplied. I fixed both issues in the code below.

I hope it helps!

```
class Point:
    def set_x(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def set_y(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def get_x(self):
        return self.x

    def get_y(self):
        return self.y


def print_list(row):
    for point in row:
        print(f"{point.get_x():.0f}, {point.get_y():.0f} | ", end="")
    print(" ;")


def print_nested_list(nested_list):
    for row in nested_list:
        for point in row:
            print(f"{point.get_x():.0f}, {point.get_y():.0f} | ", end="")
        print(" ;")


col = 0
MAX_COL = 5
row = 0
MAX_ROW = 5

column_list = []
row_list = []

while col < MAX_COL:
    col += 1
    while row < MAX_ROW:
        row += 1
        point = Point()
        point.set_x(row)
        point.set_y(col)
        row_list.append(point)
    print_list(row_list)
    column_list.append(row_list.copy())
    row = 0
    row_list.clear()

print_nested_list(column_list)
```